# Display None not output in the HTML markup

Tags: c#, html, css

I am having an issue where the style attribute display is not being outputted to screen if the display is set to 'none'. I have also tried setting property via panel.Style["display"] = "none"; but to no avail, to test to see if the display is outputted if it anything else than none i have set it to 'table' and this does output. I need to set it to none so i can animate between two panels using JQuery. The method i am using is below, this is called in the codebehind and the panel that i want to show by default doesn't have these style tags applied.

```
    private void JQueryShowPanel(Panel panelToShow)
    {
        Panel[] panels  = new Panel[] 
        {
            uxEditCallPanel,
            uxAdvancedOnePanel
        };

        foreach (Panel panel in panels)
        {
            panel.Style.Clear();
            if (panel != panelToShow)
            {        
                panel.Attributes.Add("style", "opacity: 0; height: 0px; margin-top: 100%; display: table;");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: which method are you calling, please provide some more information.

Comment: I have improved my question hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If there is no condition to triggering this logic, I propose you to do something a lot easier. Just make string variables to store these styles and write them to screen.

```
string style1 = "style='margin-top:100%;'";
string style2 = "style='display:none;'";
```

Then in your HTML element, write them in.

```
<div id="uxEditCallPanel" @style1></div>
<div id="uxAdvancedOnePanel" @style2></div>
```

Or

```
<div id="uxEditCallPanel" <%asp Response.Write(style1); %> ></div>
<div id="uxAdvancedOnePanel" <%asp Response.Write(style2); %> ></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found out what was causing the issue another JQuery Method that also set the style tag of the element was being called afterwards thus overwriting what was sent from the codebehind